# Getting past the max on a HTML slider with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks to another kind stackoverflow user, I currently have a slider that has been designed to start off in smaller increments before it gets to the larger numbers. Here is the link for that
https://snapstaging.co.uk/thirst/pricing/

While I am happy with the increments, the issue comes towards the end of the slider where the value reaches its max limit but the slider still has a portion to go.

```js
let range = document.querySelector('input[type=range]'),
  number = document.querySelector('input[type=number]');

range.min = 0;
range.max = Math.ceil(Math.log10(+number.max || 1));
range.step = +range.max / 100;

number.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  number.reportValidity();
});

range.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  number.value = 10 ** (+range.value);
  number.reportValidity();
});


number.addEventListener('invalid', function(e) {
  let v = +number.value;
  if (v > +number.max) v = +number.max;
  else if (v < +number.min) v = +number.min;
  number.value = v.toFixed();
});
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="25001" value="1">
</div>
```

I would prefer to keep the JS vanilla if possible

I would ideally like the number to keep rising (above 25001) until the slider reaches its conclusion

Comment: "*[The] issue comes towards the end of the slider where the value reaches its max limit but the slider still has a portion to go.*" - okay, but what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I would ideally like the number to keep rising (above 25001) until the slider reaches its conclusion

Comment: Thank you, could you also edit your question (the link is just below the tags) to include that information there, as comments are designed to be transitory.

Answer (score 0):

You want your slider to increment slowly initially but then increase with bigger steps.
I think you can use some kind of exponential function (e^x, 2^x, 3^x, etc.),
where `x` will the steps taken in the slider.

We can use this because of the behaviour of exponents they increase drastically when the input is big, so it fits your need that when initially x is low it will increase slowly but when x is large it increases very drastically.

[image]

I am attaching my code for your reference, you can try using this logic in your code.

```js
let number = document.querySelector('input[type=number]'); 
let a = 1;

function updateSlider(value) {
  number.value = a * Math.exp(value).toFixed();
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="10" step="0.05" value="0" oninput="updateSlider(this.value)">
  <input type="number" value="1">
</div>
```

Now let's say you want values to go from `1` to `32000`.
Then i think you can use a function `f(x) = e^x + ax + b`.
And we know `f(0) = 1`, and `f(10) = 32000`.
Try some thing like that, like using `f(x) = e^x + 1000(x)`

```js
let number = document.querySelector('input[type=number]'); 

function updateSlider(value) {
  number.value = Math.exp(value) + (1000 * value);
  number.value = Math.floor(number.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="10" step="0.05" value="0" oninput="updateSlider(this.value)">
  <input type="number" value="1">
</div>
```